# How to create new instance dynamically？

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to store some car details by sharedPreference. And there are more than one group of data. It will create new sharedPreference instance when the car number is not exist.

So the instance's name can't be same as the previous one. But I have no idea about create new instance of sharedpreference dynamically.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.search_btn:
            responseText.setText("");
            mList = new ArrayList<SharedPreferences>();
            String isNum = textNum.getText().toString();
            Iterator iterator = mList.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                if((iterator.next().toString()).equals(isNum)){
                    Log.i("information","exist!");
                    break;

                }else {
                    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("data", MODE_PRIVATE);


                    mList.add(pref);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putString("type", textType.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("num", textNum.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("car", textCar.getText().toString());
                    editor.commit();
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
     }
}
```

EDIT : I am trying to store details of a car (**vehicle type**, **plate number**, **vehicle identification number**) into `Sharedpreference`. I want to store it as a List. I want to add the details only if it does not already exist in `Sharedpreference`.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to store data by share preference, however I don't know how to create variable of sharedpreference dynamically

Comment: Why do want to create another instance?

Comment: add new car data in sharedpreference.

Comment: in sharedpreference you add key/value pairs, not new sharedpreference file for each item, what i see more suitable for your requirement is using a database (Sqlite) .

Comment: @Yazan Just to store personal car data, general one，or two cars. And I want to know how to use sharedpreference when meet such a problem.

Comment: you can use the same sharedpreference file `getSharedPreferences("data", MODE_PRIVATE)` but you can manipulate the keys, ex, `car_1_type, car_2_type, car_1_brand, car_2_brand, ...` but this could be tricky as you should assume you (as a code) don't know how many cars are there, so you can't know for how much you can go `car_10_type` exist? a workaround for this could be storing `count` in sharedpreference to know how many cars data you have, and increase/decrease this counter as user adds or deletes car from storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a POJO class to hold the details of your car.

```
private class Car {
    public String num;
    public String car;

    // getters and setters
    public void setNum(String num){
        this.num = num;
    }

    public String getNum(){
        return num;
    }


    public void setCar(String car){
        this.car = car;
    }

    public String getCar(){
        return car;
    }

}
```

You can use [GSON library](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert your list of cars to `JSON` and store it in your SharedPreferences.
The `onClick` method,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.search_btn:
            responseText.setText("");
            String isNum = textNum.getText().toString();

            // create an instance of SharedPreferences
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("data", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String value = pref.getString("cardata", "");
            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Car>>() {}.getType()
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ArrayList<Car> cars = gson.fromJson(value, type);

            // linear search
            boolean flag = false;
            for (Car car : cars) {
                if(car.num.equals(isNum)){
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // not found. add new car
            if(!flag){
                cars.add(new Car(textCar.getText().toString(), textNum.getText().toString()));
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putString("cardata", gson.toJson(cars));
                editor.apply();
            }
     }
}
```

Note : For a large number of cars, your sharedpreferences can be huge. Switch to a database if this is the case.

Comment: When first run, in fact , It's null in Json. And cars is null ----java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.ArrayList.iterator()' on a null object reference

Comment: Yeah its just the logic. You need to make a few tweaks to get it to fit your requirement. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: got it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear the topic. You will not use instance. You will use another key. It's that simple.

I'm not sure but thinking like that; you add device local a car list. Every car has a number.

You should study on key-value stuff.

Code in else block can be like that;

```
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("data", MODE_PRIVATE);  
    // mList.add(pref); i removed this line. sharedPreferences use Singleton.
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("num-" +textNum.getText().toString(), "car-" + textCar.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
```

I assume inputs are numbers, so sharedPreferences datas will be like;

```
key : num-123 value : car-123
```

And now, you can check if num-123 key exist.

Comment: Actually , the car has three details need to store. the key-value is not enough.